# Why Netty ByterBuf.readBytes will cause memory leak?

Tags: memory-leaks, netty, bytebuffer

The ByteToMessageDecoder comment that：“Some methods such as ByteBuf.readBytes(int) will cause a memory leak if the returned buffer is not released or added to the out List. Use derived buffers like ByteBuf.readSlice(int) to avoid leaking memory.”

I am a little confused, ByteBuf.readSlice will share the refCnt and the buffer with the parent, while ByteBuf.readBytes will have a new refCnt （initial is 1） and a new buffer.

So， why it will cause memory leak when I add a  new ByteBuf which is created by `ByteBuf.readBytes`?   I think I can release the new ByteBuff which added in out list, and will not cause memory leak.

And when use the ByteBuf.readSlice, it will share the refCnt with the parentBuffer, but ByteToMessageDecoder#channelRead will relase the parent Buffer, and I think it will cause that the ByteBuf which created by `readSlice`  can not be used any more.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readBytes(...)` will return a new `ByteBuf` which is allocated and so needs to be released to ensure that no memory leak will be observed. On the other hand `readSlice(...)` will just "slice" out a `ByteBuf` that points to the same internal storage and so share the same reference count as the original `ByteBuf`.

So yes if you release the buffer it will not case a memory leak.